# Retain state on new tab, but not page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to have a JS state that is retained when user opens a new tab (or new window), but is not retained on explicit page refresh. Is that possible in JS ?

So I am trying to somehow achieve reverse of what sessionStorage can give which states as per MDN docs;
*Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.*

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could keep the state in local storage. When the page is loaded, check if a session storage value exists - if so, don't retrieve the data from local storage. Otherwise, if the session storage value doesn't exist, it's a new page, in which case you can retrieve the state from local storage.

Regardless, whenever a page is loaded, set a session storage value so it can be read later by the above logic, in case the page gets refreshed.

Comment: So you are saying to have the state in both local and session storage ?
Also on page refresh, I get this state value from the server...So on first page load, I want the state from server to be set/used on my client-side, but on subsequent page loads, the UI state should be the one that should be used (ignoring the state from the server)

Comment: All you have to save in session storage is a flag indicating whether the page has been loaded before or not - if the flag doesn't exist on pageload, retrieve the actual saved state values from local storage. Otherwise, if the flag does exist, then the user has refreshed a tab, rather than loading a new one, so that's when you'd retrieve the value from the server.

Comment: I just tried...So when a new tab is opened, the session storage variable is not available on that new tab...so it is like the page is loaded for the first time....

Comment: On page refresh, I do see the updated sessionStorage variable value i.e. it says true even after I refresh

Comment: Just to add, I have created a custom hook and use as below - const [pageLoad, setPageLoad] = useSessionStorage('pageLoad', false) initially and then somewhere after initial API call, I call setPageLoad(true)